# Type of relation (between relations)

Tags: terminology, relations

Is there a word for the type of relation $R$ and $S$ are with respect to each other, if $xRy \iff ySx$?  Reciprocal relations?

Comment: If it weren't for the fact that it could be grossly misinterpreted, I would nominate "opposite".

Answer (score 1):

These are called *inverse relations*.

We can write $R = S^{-1}$ or $S^{\leftarrow}$

Note this must be true for *all* $x$ and $y$ in the domains/codomains for this.